# Login to TFS to create a bug using Visual Studio

Tags: c#

**I am getting error:**

```
TF400324: Team Foundation Services are not available from the Server.  
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server.
```

**Possible Reason for failure include:**
- The name, port number or protocol for the Team Foundation server is incorrect.
- Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace TFS_CreateBug_POC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("userId", "password");
            BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(credential);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("url"), basicCred);
            tpc.Authenticate();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Console Output:** `Connected`

**Actual Console Output:**

```
TF400324: Team Foundation Services are not available from the Server  
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server
```

Comment: Assuming you have checked all possible causes for the error, are you probably dealing with an `https` URL that has an invalid/self signed certificate? This is something the TFS client in VS really doesn't like. Also which versions of TFS and VS are you talking about?

Comment: No I am using "http" url.
TFS Version: Version 16.131.28507.4
VS: 2015